# dealing with 'undefined' properties in Meteor.method

Tags: meteor, fullcontact

I've created a function in my Meteor application, which is set to 'enrich' the data contained within a meteor collection. The function is meant to iterate over a collection, utilize the [fullcontact API](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/) to pull additional data on all the client entries maintained within the db (i.e. LinkedIn Bio; no. of employees, etc.).

The issue lies around the fact that not all datapoint are available for all elements within the collection (e.g. a client may not have a LinkedIn profile). The function works for the initial couple of elements but eventually fails throwing a `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`, because the `data variable` does not contain a LinkedIn Profile bio for the company (for this particular example).

What do you suggest as a workout? Any ideas? Your help would be much appreciated - I have been at this for a couple of hours.

```
Meteor.methods({
  enrichment() {
    var fullcontact = new FullContact(Meteor.settings.fullContact);
    for (var i = 1; i < customerDb.find({ company: "Qualify" }).count(); i++) {
      var url = customerDb.findOne( { company: "Qualify", 'item.clientId': i.toString() } )['item']['contact_website'];
      var data = fullcontact.company.domain(url);
      if ( data['status'] == 200 ) {
        customerDb.update ({ 
          company: "Qualify", 'item.clientId': i.toString()
        }, {
          $push: {
            bio: data['socialProfiles'][2]['bio'],
            keywords: data['organization']['keywords'],
            employees: data['organization']['approxEmployees'],
            domesticTrafficRank: data['traffic']['topCountryRanking'][0],
            globalTrafficRank: data['traffic']['ranking'][0]
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Data could not be found on the company')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If `data['socialProfiles'][2]` doesn't exist, what's stopping you from just checking for existence? like `(data['socialProfiles'][2] || {})['bio']`? Or is there somewhere else you could get the bio from?

Comment: Hi @chazsolo : I think I broadly understand what you are pointing at - but I'm trying to avoid a situation where I'm constructing multiple `if (typeof data['socialProfiles']['2'] === 'undefined' || variable === null){} else` statements within my method - I was hoping for something cleaner, more elegant. Also - I don't know how I could check for existences within the meteor.update function (would it work?). Thanks for your quick response - appreciate your thoughts on this! Philipp

Comment: One way or another you'll have to check for object existence when dealing with nested properties. You could either do it inline (as I suggested above) or before the `customerDb.update` call. That way, you could build up the object to push before the call and you'd be left with something like: `$push: updatedCustomerData`

Comment: @chazsolo thanks for this - that makes sense, I will give that a try tomorrow (the latter) and let you know!

Comment: Any luck? If you need an example I'd be happy to post an answer for ya

Comment: @chazsolo It's proving a late day in the office (I'm based in the UK), haven't had a chance to try - I'd greatly appreciate an example but otherwise give me a day and I will try your idea by Saturday noon.

Comment: Take a shot at it - I'll keep an eye on your question!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @chazsolo's suggestion, you can deal with potentially missing data and keys with javascript ANDs and ORs. This is a common defensive coding pattern.

Here each item will be replaced with an empty string if any of the parent keys are missing or the array element is missing. You can simplify this if you know more about what can be missing. Also you may want numbers instead of strings in some of these cases.

```
if ( data['status'] == 200 ) {
  const bio = data['socialProfiles'] && data['socialProfiles'][2] && data['socialProfiles'][2]['bio'] || '';
  const keywords = data['organization'] && data['organization']['keywords'] || '';
  const employees = data['organization'] && data['organization']['approxEmployees'] || '',
  const domesticTrafficRank = data['traffic'] && data['traffic']['topCountryRanking'] && data['traffic']['topCountryRanking'][0] || '',
  const globalTrafficRank = data['traffic'] && data['traffic']['ranking'] && data['traffic']['ranking][0] || '';

  customerDb.update (
    { company: "Qualify", 'item.clientId': i.toString() },
    { $push: { bio, keywords, employees, domesticTrafficRank, globalTrafficRank }}
  });
```